# How to determine when remote display drops frames?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

When I cast via the `Remote Display API`, sometimes I notice the receiver application drop frames. Is there a way to programmatically determine when frame drop occurs?

Comment: I have no way to test this but I chased TCP RST / NACK (or timing ACKs) as an idea. This may also give some hints? https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=934

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote), it shows that [rendering to the remote display session](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote#rendering-to-the-remote-display-session) feature is already available for iOS framework. However, you may try if it is possible in Android since it was mentioned that Google Cast Remote Display API (being in beta version), features may change even before official release.

Other implementation that you can do and is already currently available (unfortunately, I  haven't actually used it) is through classes that are used to manage various media interfaces as given in [android.media](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html). For Android, you can try using [**`MediaCodec.OnFrameRenderedListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.OnFrameRenderedListener.html). It is a listener to be called when an output frame has rendered on the output surface.

On the other hand, you may also use the [Google Cast Remote Display plugin for Unity](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote_unity#implementing-the-ux) to be able to use additional classes that are only for [Remote Display Unity Plugin](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/unity/).

For more detailed information, please try going through the given documentations and you may also check these helpful references:

- [Google Cast Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes) to be always updated on new releases that can help you with your concern.
- [GoogleCastRemoteDisplay in GitHub](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cast-unity-plugin/tree/master/end_project/Assets/Plugins/GoogleCastRemoteDisplay)
- [issue in tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=494) regarding Chromecast dropping frames while buffering for higher quality streams.